# I can´t change display resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I already have Ubuntu installed and everything worked but suddenly I have a resolution of 1024x768 on the fullhd monitor and when I go to the settings there is no option to change the resolution.

I tried disconnecting and connecting all the cables but it still doesn't work. I also have windows and everything works there but on Ubuntu no. I tried the terminal too, the error tutorials always don't work.

[image]

This is the monitor: https://www.philips.cz/c-p/24M1N3200VA_00/gaming-monitor-herni-monitor-full-hd-lcd

Ubuntu version:Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: What graphics card do you have?  Have you checked to see if you have any updated drivers for your GPU?

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me, please try it.

Run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` then restart your machine.

Comment: this worked for me too. thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem; I did these steps to fix it.

1. Go to software & updates.
2. Additional Drivers
3. In NVIDIA Corporation dropdown, change the driver to another one that is (proprietary). In my case, I had 3 I tried all of them, but nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary) worked for me.
4. Restart.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I encounter issues like this, I run `xrandr` to show available output modes.

Then you can manually set the output with something like: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary  --mode 1920x1080 -r 60`

Comment: OP is on 22.04, and that uses the Wayland display manager by default. We don't know whether OP switched to the optional Xorg or not. It's relevant, because `xrandr` works only on Xorg.